# How to build a mailto HTML element in PHP with URL with GET vars in body

Tags: php, html

I'm building a 'mailto' HTML element in my PHP program and the constructed code is as follows:

```
    <a href="mailto:some.one@some.where.com
            ?Subject=CA-7%20graphing%20tool%20error report
            &body=Problem with graph http://mcz:51019/noSecurePhp/graphBuildTest.php?startJobname=PE2300DY&amp;endJobnames=&amp;jobMask=&amp;collapseJobnames=&amp;searchDepth=1&amp;schedId=001&amp;custSchedule=&amp;cpColour=%23ffff00&amp;cpStartEndColour=%23ff0000&amp;grpBySuite=on&amp;maxNodes=500&amp;ranksep=0.5&amp;nodesep=0.25&amp;layout=dot&amp;splines=spline&amp;rankDir=TB&amp;graphStyle=Full&amp;bgColour=%23a8a8a8&amp;nodeColour=%23ffc68c&amp;fontColour=%23000000&amp;nodeStyle=filled&amp;penWidth=3%20Issue description :" target="_blank" class="btn btn-danger">Send Bug report</a>
```

The button looks fine and the URL that shows in the status bar when I hover over it looks ok, although the '&' just shows as '&' i.e. the URL looks correct.

When I click the button, I get a new email with the correct address and subject, but the body is just:

```
Problem with graph http://mcz:51019/noSecurePhp/graphBuildTest.php?startJobname=PE2300DY+
```

i.e. cut off at the first '&'.

Here's the code that builds the mailto element (NL is just "
\n") :

```
function createBugbutton() {
    $invokingUrl = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    $invokingUrl = str_replace(["&", "#", " "], ["&amp;", "%23", "%20"], $invokingUrl);

    $emailBody = "Problem with graph ".$invokingUrl.NL.NL."Issue description :";

    $emailLink = '<a href="mailto:some.one@some.where.com
            ?Subject=CA-7%20graphing%20tool%20error report
            &body='.$emailBody.'"
            target="_blank" class="btn btn-danger"
            >Send Bug report</a>';

    echo $emailLink;
}
```

I have copied the generated HTML into a blank HTML file and that behaves exactly the same, so I don't think it's a PHP thing.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: following comments and answers, my generated HTML is now:

```
<a href="mailto:some.one@some.where.com
                ?Subject=error report
                &body=Problem with graph http://mcz/graphBuildTest.php?startJobname=PE2300DY&26;endJobnames=fred<br>
Issue description :" target="_blank" class="btn btn-danger"
                >Send Bug report</a>
```

but even this cppied into an .html file file to build the email with the body again stopping after the 'PE2300DY'

New edit:

Working following the accepted answer - thanks all.

Comment: use [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) vs manually doing it, also your need it for `NL` presuming that means new line

Comment: Still not working. See addition to question.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `&amp;` with `%26`

I tested this and it works:

```
<a href="mailto:some.one@some.where.com
        ?Subject=CA-7%20graphing%20tool%20error report
        &body=Problem with graph http://mcz:51019/noSecurePhp/graphBuildTest.php?startJobname=PE2300DY%26endJobnames=%26jobMask=%26collapseJobnames=%26searchDepth=1%26schedId=001%26custSchedule=%26cpColour=%23ffff00%26cpStartEndColour=%23ff0000%26grpBySuite=on%26maxNodes=500%26ranksep=0.5%26nodesep=0.25%26layout=dot%26splines=spline%26rankDir=TB%26graphStyle=Full%26bgColour=%23a8a8a8%26nodeColour=%23ffc68c%26fontColour=%23000000%26nodeStyle=filled%26penWidth=3%20Issue description :" target="_blank" class="btn btn-danger">Send Bug report</a>
```

Your function should be:

```
function createBugbutton() {
    $invokingUrl = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    $invokingUrl = str_replace(["&", "#", " "], ["%26", "%23", "%20"], $invokingUrl);

    $emailBody = "Problem with graph ".$invokingUrl.NL.NL."Issue description :";

    $emailLink = '<a href="mailto:some.one@some.where.com
            ?Subject=CA-7%20graphing%20tool%20error report
            &body='.$emailBody.'"
            target="_blank" class="btn btn-danger"
            >Send Bug report</a>';

    echo $emailLink;
}
```

Comment: More information: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: Yep that works when I copy the code into a simply HTML file - problem now between keyboard and screen!

Comment: All i did was replace the &amp; with %26. the function above should do the trick

Comment: Thanks Dan - is there any way to get the 'Issue Description: ' text with some blank lines, as the NL or even '\n' before it isn't doing the trick. I want users to enter their own description of the issue here.

Comment: Try $emailBody = "Problem with graph ".$invokingUrl."\r\n"."\r\n"."Issue description :";